# git rebase implementation details

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to figure out the working mechanism of `git-rebase`. [Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) provides information about what `git-rebase` does, but doesn't comment on how it does?

I have looked into the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-rebase.sh), worked out some test cases and so far understand following:
 1. Git maintains the state of rebase in `.git/rebase-apply` (with files like patch, final-commit, head-name etc)
 2. Git uses `git-format-patch` to create all necessary patch files (which are inside rebase-apply)
 3. Git uses `git-am` to apply those patches one by one

I think I am missing quite a lot of details. Where can I find the implementation details? Is it simply dumping the patch and naively applying it?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11566503/2949612) answer.

Comment: @pRaNaY, that answer is more about what git rebase does. I am looking for how it does?

Comment: Why don't you dig into the code itself? :)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase contains a lot of explanation on the various options and strategies used while rebasing. You should also look into the docs of the `rerere` configuration

Comment: @EvertonAgner, yes, I have tried looking into their code. I have been able to understand some details, but might be missing a lot.

Comment: Rebase, in its simple form, is essentially a series of `cherry-pick`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your summary is basically complete.  Rebase is actually relatively simple.

1. First, the work to do is calculated.  This is basically `git rev-list <upstream>..<branch>` to identify all the commits that need to be moved over.
2. The needed information to perform the rebase is created in a state folder in the `.git` directory. There are two primary rebase backends, which each use a different folder:

   - For an apply rebase (patch-based, currently the default), patches for each of the commits will be generated and saved in `.git/rebase-apply`
   - For a merge rebase (used for e.g. interactive rebases), a todo list containing a list of commits and how to apply them will be generated in `.git/rebase-merge`
   - For both backends, other files containing information such as references to the target and original commits are generated and stored in the state folder.
3. Next, the `HEAD` is detached and set to the `onto` commit (the new base branch, where you will be applying those changes).
4. Application takes place until a commit cannot be applied.

   - For a patch-based rebase, then patches are applied in order.  If a patch fails to apply, then Git will try to instead `cherry-pick` the commit in question.  This is because `cherry-pick` is able to write merge conflicts to the index and working directory.
   - For a merge-based rebase, then the commit is `cherry-pick`ed.
5. If a `cherry-pick` fails with conflicts, rebase stops and you (the user) must resolve any conflicts and `git add` them to the index.  When you have resolved all conflicts, you can `git rebase --continue`.
6. Once all conflicts have been applied, the original branch is updated to point to the final, rebased commit.

---

Some closing details on backends:
The merge backend was originally just the interactive rebase backend. It can be invoked manually with the `--merge` option, and is also used as the default backend for `--onto` among others. The apply backend is older, and may eventually be replaced entirely by the merge backend.

Comment: In a normal (patch-based) rebase, how are the patches generated? Is each patch the diff of the commit vs its parent, or is it more like a diff of the commit vs the branch you are rebasing onto?

Comment: It's a diff against it's parent.  (A diff against the branch you're rebasing onto would include all the changes that are unique to one of the branches; a diff against the parent isolates the changes to a single commit.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was very helpful! I've edited this question to add more detail on the different backends, as I came here to understand an interactive rebase, which uses the merge backend. I think my edits are all sound, but feel free to re-edit as you see fit or if I missed something :)